use hive hash function inside spark sql - spark 3.5
I have an spark job wherein I need to read data from hive (hive 3) and insert it to MySQL. Before reading there needs a data refresh that needs to happen. The refresh query looks like this (Only providing the code which needs attention):
Insert overwrite schema_x.table_x    
SELECT distinct
         CASE WHEN hash(email_name) < 0 THEN (hash(email_name) * -1)
              WHEN hash(email_name) > 0 THEN hash(email_name)
         END as id,
         trim(email_name) as name,
         camp_id
    from schema.table_name

The job is a part of Airflow DAG wherein previously the query was run via Hive Operator. So, the above query used hash function from hive catalog. But, as I am moving this to be run via spark-sql, it is using spark-sql's implementation of hash leading to different result.
My queries are as follows:

Can I force spark to use hive's hash implementation? If so, how?
Can UDF declarations help here? If so, is there a way to call hive's hash inside the udf directly instead of re-implementing the internal workings?
Can this be achieved via DataFrame APIs?
If the above options are out of scope, what is the best way to tackle the scenario?

Thanks.
